# error: indirection requires pointer operand ('int' invalid)

Tags: c

The purpose of this code is to pass a virtual address in decimal and output the page number and offset.

After I compile my code using the gcc compiler on Linux I get this error:

> indirection requires pointer operand ('int' invalid)
>         virtualAddress = *atoi(argv[1]);

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <curses.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[])

{

     unsigned long int virtualAddress,pageNumber,offset;

     if(argc<2){

          printf(" NO ARGUMNET IS PASSED");

          return 0;

     }

    virtualAddress = *atoi(argv[1]);

     //PRINT THE VIRTUAL ADDRESS

    printf("The Address %lu contains:",virtualAddress);

    //CALCULATE THE PAGENUMBER

    pageNumber = virtualAddress/4096;

     //PRINT THE PAGE NUMBER

    printf("\n Page Number = %lu",pageNumber);

    //FIND THE OFFSET

    offset = virtualAddress%4096;

    //PRINTS THE OFFSET

    printf("\n Offset = %lu",offset);

     getch();

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 9):

This error occurs when you want to create pointer to your variable by `*my_var` instead of `&my_var`.

Answer (score 5):

```
virtualAddress = *atoi(argv[1]);
```

`atoi` function returns `int` (not `int *` *so no need to dereference return value*) and you try to dereference `int` , therefore , compiler gives an error.

As you need it in `unsinged long int` use [`strtoul`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtoul.htm) -

```
char * p;
virtualAddress = strtoul(argv[1], &p,10);
```

Comment: @azizoh - If the answer from ameyCU solved your problem, you should strongly consider to accept the answer